# OpenCV 3.0 NormalBayesClassifier predict error

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, opencv3.0, naivebayes

I am using OpenCV 3.0.0 in C++ for training a Normal Bayes Classifier. I trained the classifier, and stored it to a file. Now I am trying to use the classifier to predict the responses. Here is the relevant code:

```
Ptr<TrainData> trainingData = TrainData::loadFromCSV(trainingDataFile,0);
std::cout << "Training data has been loaded.\n";
Mat samples = trainingData->getTrainSamples();
Mat correctResponses = trainingData->getTrainResponses();

std::cout << "Loading NB classifier...\n";
Ptr<NormalBayesClassifier> nbClassifier = NormalBayesClassifier::load<NormalBayesClassifier>(trainingDataFile+"_trainedNBParams.dat");
std::cout << "NB classifier loaded.\n";

Mat receivedResponses;
std::cout << "Classifying data using NB classifier...\n";
nbClassifier->predict(samples,receivedResponses); //error here
std::cout << "Classification complete.\n";
```

I am getting the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Null pointer (When the number of input samples is >1, the output vector of results must be passed) in predictProb, file /home/keyur/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/modules/ml/src/nbayes.cpp, line 318
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/keyur/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/modules/ml/src/nbayes.cpp:318: error: (-27) When the number of input samples is >1, the output vector of results must be passed in function predictProb
```

I do not understand how the output matrix is supposed to be passed to the function. The documentation is rather vague, and other StackOverflow answers are rather unhelpful for this specific problem.

Documentation link:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d4/d8e/classcv_1_1ml_1_1NormalBayesClassifier.html

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to a bug in OpenCV 3.0.0 which has been fixed in OpenCV 3.1.0.